# PDB corresponding to a binary

Tags: c++, .net

We have different versions of binary kept in SVN. We also keeps the pdb files corresponding to the binaries. Sometimes the developers check-in the wrong pdb files. This creates problems when an issue is reported by a client at a later point.

Is there any tools to check whether a pdb file corresponds to a binary?

Comment: Most people don't check in their PDB files (and create a rule to ignore them)... any particular reason you're checking your PDB files in?

Comment: In the long term, consider setting up a build server - it could commit the binaries and PDB files to SVN automatically after a successful build.

Comment: We are using PDB files to analyze crash dump

Comment: http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2011/06/28/does-that-pdb-file-match-the-binary.aspx

Comment: You really should not have developers checking in pdb files or making builds.  This should rather be done on a single dedicated machine.  Ideally this process should br automated.

Comment: So is this C++ or .NET or both? The tags are confusing.

Comment: This is for both c++ and .net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this tool - [ChkMatch](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html). This both checks the match and also allows you to forcefully match(i.e. allow you to use wrong pdbs as long as they are not too different from the actual ones). Read through this [page](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/debuginfomatch.html).